# Receive notifications from a server to web application

Tags: javascript, push-notification

My web application executes a long running process and, upon completion, needs to notify the user.

Currently I am using `setinterval` to periodically query the server (Flask) about the state of the calculation. Something like:

```
function start_check_mesh_timer (ip_address, case_name) {
  clearInterval(check_mesh_timer)
  check_mesh_timer = setInterval(function () {
    check_mesh(ip_address, case_name)
  }, 3000)
}
```

I would like to use a push notification instead. I am not an expert in web development and could not find a simple example. Can you suggest what approach to follow or where to look?

I am not looking for code, just for some directions..

Comment: you may want to consider service workers if you care about efficiency, it would be more work but it may or may not be worth the efforts ;) alternatively, you can think about using realdatabase from firebase (if this is something you can take on)

Answer (score 1):

Better create WebSocket endpoint on backend and create WebSocket connection on client side.

WebSocket: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Flask WebSocket articles:

- https://medium.com/swlh/implement-a-websocket-using-flask-and-socket-io-python-76afa5bbeae1
- https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/